# Performing action on each selected item in Listbox VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am populating a listbox with a large list. The user then has the option of choosing multiple items from this list. I then want to perfrom a few actions on only the selected items.

I cant figure out how to only perform the actions on only the highlighted selections.

```
'I have tried all combinations of

For each Listbx.SelectedItems.ToString in ListBx.Items.ToString
For each Listbx.SelectedItem in Listbx.Items 
'etc, etc

''Performing actions here but it is still doing it with all entries

Next
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
For Each selecteditem As [Object] In Listbx.SelectedItems
    //Your code on each item
Next
```